# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file in windows

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I tried installing maven multiple times on my windows 10 but "mvn --version" cmd gives the same error every time". The path settings are shown below.

```
C:\Users\eztrias>**echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181**

C:\Users\eztrias>**echo %MAVEN_HOME%
C:\apache-maven-3.6.3**

C:\Users\eztrias>echo %PATH%
C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\bin\x32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core;C:\Program Files\VanDyke Software\Clients\;**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin**;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\eztrias\go\bin;C:\Users\eztrias\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;**C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin**;
```

What should I do more ?

Comment: environment settings look fine, just restart the machine

Comment: You may also need the M2_HOME environment variable to be set. Remember also to close the command window and open a new one to pick up env changes every time you change env variables.

Comment: Also check for the `C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin` folder exists.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam yes, it exists. But it's still not working.